# Enable TLS for Rabbitmq Management Plugin

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to configure the management plugin to use TLS but each time I'm getting the following error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Jun-2016::15:52:19 ===
SSL: certify: tls_connection.erl:375:Fatal error: decode error

=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Jun-2016::15:52:19 ===
    application: mochiweb
    "Accept failed error"
    "{error,{tls_alert,\"decode error\"}}"
```

I wan't to use the same certs that I'm using with nginx running on the same server, nginx configuration is the following:

```
...
        ssl_certificate     /var/certs/crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /var/certs/key;
...
```

they are pem encoded and `crt` is a chained certificate

my rabbitmq.config is following:

```
[{rabbitmq_management,
  [{listener, [{port,     15672},
               {ssl,      true},
               {ssl_opts, [{cacertfile, "/var/certs/ca.pem"},
                           {certfile,   "/var/certs/crt"},
                           {keyfile,    "/var/certs/key"}]}
              ]}
  ]}].
```

`ca.pem` is the root CA certificate from which I obtained my server cert.
How can I diagnose what's the problem?

When I follow the [RabbitMQ SSL Guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html) with self signed certificates everything works but I would really like to use the one I already have.

RabbitMQ 3.5.6, Erlang R16B03

Comment: it seems that you have an error in your certificate.

Comment: it could be something related to the cyphers suite, It is not able to decode or not decode your specific certificate.

Comment: I've gave up on this and configured a reverse-proxy (nginx) for that

Comment: putting it behind nginx or apache is a good way to set this up. Then you can auto-refresh the certificate with certbot as well.

Answer (score 0):

> they are pem encoded and crt is a chained certificate

`certfile` needs to be a path to standalone certificate, not a chained certificate.